# How to Import .adapter files to Ibm Mobilefirst 7.1 which were created in Ibm worklight 6.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have a worklight project to import to my Eclipse MFP 7.1

- I'm bit unclear of how importing .adapter files generate in IBM Worklight 6.1
- If I import selecting archive file and creating the same folder structure, I get an issue like Invalid xml schema

Please help me out of importing the .adapter correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no import specifically for adapters.

Adapters are part of a project, and so you need to import the entire project. This will also enable the MobileFirst Upgrader to modify the adapter's XML structure to the recommended one in 7.1.

That, or you create a new adapter in your 7.1 project and copy-paste into it the contents of the XML and JS files from your original 6.1 adapter.